# Is it possible to train the neural networks for programming

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, data-mining, bigdata

I want to train my neural networks for the task of programming in a different language. So, I want to know whether is it possible or not to train a neural net for programming?

Comment: Can you clarify what you consider a successful programming AI? The output is clearly some working code. But what is the input? Some code in a different language? A UML diagram of the system? A maths problem to solve? An English (or other human language) description of the problem? The nature of the input makes a huge difference to the feasibility and possible approaches.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of functionality you would want to achieve. In essence, a trained neural network is a mapping function, which takes some input and produces some output, which then may be variously interpreted (for example using a certain threshold for classification).

Therefore, if the desired functionality of your program would be coming up with a computational function, you could treat your trained neural network as the program itself. Multiple machine learning libraries allow that easily, producing a class instance which contains the trained neural network inside and allows you to call it with given parameters just like any other function.

However, I assume that you are looking for a way to output complex computer code with control structures, etc. - that unfortunately is very difficult to achieve, since you'd need an effective way to interpret the neural network outputs as code - not just the commands, but their structure and ordering as well. Such interpretations would be so complex that they'd make it very difficult for any Neural Network training method to converge to anything sensible.

To mitigate this problem, you can try machine learning techniques which manipulate and optimize the code "directly". The most famous of such is Genetic Programming - in which a computer program in encoded as a set of "genes" which are then improved upon through genetic algorithm techniques (crossovers which recombine large parts of code and mutations which randomly change small parts of the code). This has been successfully applied to some programming problems such as the Towers of Hanoi (see http://www.oakgp.org/towers-of-hanoi ).

Answer (score 1):

François Chollet addresses this in his book, [Deep Learning with Python](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python):

> **9.2 The limitations of deep learning**
>
> The space of applications that can be
> implemented with deep learning is nearly infinite. And yet, many
> applications are completely out of reach for current deep-learning
> techniques—even given vast amounts of human-annotated data. Say, for
> instance, that you could assemble a dataset of hundreds of
> thousands—even millions—of English-language descriptions of the
> features of a software product, written by a product manager, as well
> as the corresponding source code developed by a team of engineers to
> meet these requirements. Even with this data, you could *not* train a
> deep-learning model to read a product description and generate the
> appropriate codebase. That’s just one example among many. In general,
> anything that requires reasoning—like programming or applying the
> scientific method—long-term planning, and algorithmic data
> manipulation is out of reach for deep-learning models, no matter how
> much data you throw at them. Even learning a sorting algorithm with a
> deep neural network is tremendously difficult.
>
> This is because a
> deep-learning model is just a *chain of simple, continuous geometric
> transformations* mapping one vector space into another. All it can do
> is map one data manifold X into another manifold Y , assuming the
> existence of a learnable continuous transform from X to Y . A
> deep-learning model can be interpreted as a kind of program; but,
> inversely, *most programs can’t be expressed as deep-learning
> models*—for most tasks, either there exists no corresponding
> deep-neural network that solves the task or, even if one exists, it
> may not be *learnable*: the corresponding geometric transform may be far
> too complex, or there may not be appropriate data available to learn
> it.
>
> Scaling up current deep-learning techniques by stacking more
> layers and using more training data can only superficially palliate
> some of these issues. It won’t solve the more fundamental problems
> that deep-learning models are limited in what they can represent and
> that most of the programs you may wish to learn can’t be expressed as
> a continuous geometric morphing of a data manifold.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of in the literature is pix2code, where the authors trained a GAN to generate simple DSL code for a UI based on an input image of the intended UI layout.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07962.pdf